# How do I find a substring within a string in F#?

Tags: f#, substring

I found a "fun" project online for f# and the idea behind it is to find the number of substrings within a given string.

Here's the prompt:

```
Description:
You are given a DNA sequence:
a string that contains only characters 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T'.
Your task is to calculate the number of substrings of sequence,
in which each of the symbols appears the same number of times.

Example 1:
For sequence = "ACGTACGT", the output should be 6
All substrings of length 4 contain each symbol exactly once (+5),
and the whole sequence contains each symbol twice (+1).

Example 2:
For sequence = "AAACCGGTTT", the output should be 1
Only substring "AACCGGTT" satisfies the criterion above: it contains each symbol twice.


Input: String, a sequence that consists only of symbols 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T'.
Length constraint: 0 < sequence.length < 100000.

Output: Integer, the number of substrings where each symbol appears equally many times.
```

I'm not exactly sure where to go with this, or more specifically what to do.  I've looked around on the internet to try and find what I'm supposed to do and I've only found the following code (I added the input variable, var variable, and changed the show "things" to **input** then the substring to search for (i hope that makes sense)):

```
open System

let countSubstring (where :string) (what : string) =
match what with
| "" -> 0
| _ -> (where.Length - where.Replace(what, @"").Length) / what.Length


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

let input = System.Console.ReadLine();
let var = input.Length;
Console.WriteLine(var);
let show where what =
    printfn @"countSubstring(""%s"", ""%s"") = %d" where what (countSubstring where what)
show input "ACGT"
show input "CGTA"
show input "GTAC"
show input "TACG"
0
```

Anyways, if anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to look into regex - which can have multiple matches

Comment: Even if you were able to produce code that seems to be working, how will you know that it actually works? If you input a 99987-digit string, how will you verify that the returned number is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First declare a function `numberACGT` that  from a string returns 1 if the number of characters A is the same as C, G and T and 0 otherwise. For this, declare an array N of 4 integers initialized to 0 and run throw the string, incrementing the corresponding counter. In late compare array elements between them.

Then for each sub-string (fixed length multiple of 4) call `numberACGT` and add to counter `count` (initialized to 0 at the beginning)

```
let numberACGT (aString:string) =
    let N = Array.create 4 (0:int)
    let last = aString.Length - 1 
    for i = 0 to last do
        match aString.[i] with
        | 'A' -> N.[0] <- N.[0] + 1
        | 'C' -> N.[1] <- N.[1] + 1
        | 'G' -> N.[2] <- N.[2] + 1
        | _ -> N.[3] <- N.[3] + 1
    if (N.[0] = N.[1]) && (N.[1] = N.[2]) && (N.[2] = N.[3]) then 1 else 0 

let numberSubStrings (aString:string) =
    let mutable count = 0
    let len = aString.Length 
    for k = 1 to len / 4 do //only multiple of 4
        for pos = 0 to len - 4*k do
            count <- count + numberACGT (aString.[pos..pos+4*k-1])
    count
```

I hope that it is fast enough.

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()
  let input =  Console.ReadLine() in
    printf "%i  " (numberSubStrings input)
  stopWatch.Stop()
  let g =  Console.ReadLine()
  0
```

Result:

```
62    4.542700
```

An new version in O(n²):

```
let numberSubStringsBis (aString:string) =
    let mutable count = 0 
    let len = aString.Length 
    for pos = 0 to len - 1 do
        let mutable a = 0 
        let mutable  c = 0 
        let mutable g = 0 
        let mutable t = 0 
        let mutable k = pos 
        while k + 3 <= len - 1 do
            for i in [k..k+3] do
                match aString.[i] with
                | 'A' -> a <- a + 1
                | 'C' -> c <- c + 1
                | 'G' -> g <- g + 1
                | _ -> t <- t + 1
            k <- k + 4 
            if a=c && c=g && g=t then count <- count + 1               
    count
```

Comment: First off, I wanted to thank you very much for you help.

Comment: do you know how i  can add a console input into the code below where you said "i hope that this is fast enough".  i've tried adding a "let input = console.readline" then replacing the string with 'var' (and i added a "let var = input.ToString) but i get an error that says "This expression was expected to have type string but here has type unit->string"  do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Thank you. I have replaced in the answer. `Console.ReadLine` returns a string so you can work directly with the result. You must add () after `Console.ReadLine`, which awaits the type unit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that generates all substrings that have length divisible by four and then counts how many of those have equal amount of symbols. Note that if the length of a substring is not divisible by four it cannot have equal amount of four different symbols.

```
let hasEqualAmountOfSymbols (substring : string) =
    let symbolAppearances =
        ['A'; 'C'; 'G'; 'T']
        |> List.map (fun symbol ->
            substring
            |> Seq.filter ((=) symbol)
            |> Seq.length)
    symbolAppearances
    |> List.pairwise
    |> List.forall (fun (x, y) -> x = y)


let countSubstrings input =
    let potentialSubstrings =
        let lastIndex = String.length input - 1
        [ for i in 0 .. lastIndex do
            for j in i + 3 .. 4 .. lastIndex do
                yield input.Substring(i, j - i + 1) ]
    potentialSubstrings
    |> List.filter hasEqualAmountOfSymbols
    |> List.length


countSubstrings "ACGTACGT" // -> 6
countSubstrings "AAACCGGTTT" // -> 1
```

Comment: Note that this brute force solution doesn't scale well to the allowable problem size (strings of length 99999).  For example, running on a string of length 2000 takes about 20s on my machine.

Comment: @kvb Yes, this is a brute force solution with O(n^2) complexity. This can be easily made ten times faster with mutable data structures, but I guess it is quite tricky to come up with an algorithm with better complexity.

Comment: Actually I believe it's O(n^3) because of the need to apply `hasEqualAmountOfSymbols` to each candidate.  You can certainly achieve true O(n^2) behavior.